# OSX Screensaver photo repeat problem

Tags: macos, imac, photos, screensaver

I have an iMac running OSX 10.8.4 and I have a large collection of photos (10,000+) that I want displayed during the screensaver.  I would like to see a uniform distribution of all photos.  However, I am finding that there is only a small subset of the photos that are actually shown, and there are many repeats.  It is my hypothesis that OSX is choosing a subset of photos (say, 100) at the beginning of the Screensaver session, and that it is just cycling through these.
My question: is there a setting to change the number of photos that the screensaver uses?

I am comfortable with bash shell commands and am happy to modify plist files.

Thanks.  Kevin.

Comment: I've also found that the first photo that is displayed in the screensaver is ALWAYS the same.  Haven't noticed the limited distribution issue though.  Currently on Mac OS 10.7.5

Comment: That is difficult task. The reason it always start from beginning is it newer finished to display all, so it starts over each time it is interrupted. If you have 10000 photos with display time of 3.6 seconds = 36000 seconds or 10 Hours. So to see all photos you will have to wait for 10 hours.

Comment: I've been giving this a lot more thought and watching the screensaver (alot).  I still think that the images repeat on certain settings.

Comment: I do not find that it starts at the same photo each time.  It does start with a new one.  However, the screensaver seems to grab a set of photos and then simply cycles through that set.  That is, until the screensaver is restarted, then a new set is chosen.

Comment: Has anyone found a way to address this?  I'm running the origami screen saver now on OSX 10.10.3 and it repeats every 20 pages or so.  I'm guessing that it caches the pre-rendered pages when it starts the screensaver.  There must be a setting somewhere to set choose how many pages to cache.

Comment: Its six years later and still no answer.  Certainly there is a setting to tweak the size of the image cache for the screensaver.  Anyone?  Anyone?